# Wants to save Instagram post and comments on post to our domain, is it possible and if possible how?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have a domain which have a feature to login with instagram a/c, registered users associate their instagram a/c using this process.

Now i want to store/save all post and comments of users they have posted on instagram a/c.

So that i can perform a search on comments and caption of posts.

As fas as my knowledge its not possible by using instagram api thats why i am saving info in my database.

Is there any simple way to perform search ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instagram only gives you 150 latest comments via API, so if you want to search through all comments, you have fetch comments at regular interval and save on server, searching these comments are straight forward, look for substring in the comment items saved. It is kind of tricky on deciding how often you want to check for comments and store, usually mosts comments are posted few minutes after a popular photo is posted. If you do the checks too often, you may reach the API rate limit.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

If you are dealing with less than 150 comments on average, then you can search through it without needing to save on server and can be done all on client side. Just pull the comments using API and do search through the array of comments using javascript.

[Picodash](https://www.picodash.com) allows you to view the latest 150 comments and search any keyword or user, here is screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have developed library in php: https://github.com/raiym/instagram-php-scraper

It allows you to get ALL comments from specific post (I have tested with 8 000 comments)

```
$comments = Instagram::getMediaCommentsByCode('BGY0zB4r7X2', 1500);
```